# What is the PHP regex to get the parent directory of a page?

Tags: php, regex

I have a page at:

`http://somewebsite.com/1234/test/`

How do I get the `1234` extracted from it with a PHP regex?

Comment: if the url is http://somewebsite.com/1234/test/directory/ do you want the "test" part or the "1234" part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to avoid regex if I don't need it, so I would recommend you do it this way:

```
$url = explode("/", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Then you can reference the part of the url that you want using this:

```
$url[1]
```

If you need/want to use regex, I'll think about it for a second and try to post a solution later.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use RegEx use **[`parse_url()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)** and **[`explode()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)**.

---

For one level up, use **[`dirname()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)**

Answer (score 1):

To just get the one above you can use

```
echo dirname("http://www.google.com/cake/lol");
```

Outputs

> http://www.google.com/cake

Or for just the bit between the / and / you could do

```
var_dump(explode("/", "http://www.google.com/cake/lol"));
```

Or in regex

```
preg_match_all('@/([^/]*)/@',$sourcestring,$matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform regex on `$_SCRIPT['REQUEST_URL']` or split it by '/' and get the first element => 1234

Answer (score 0):

If the PHP was triggered by launching that URL, then these will probably be true:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/1234/test/"

dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == "/1234"

basename(dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) == "1234"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match(".*\/(\w+)\/(\w+)\/", "$url", $matches);
```

The parent directory is `$matches[1]`.